# Django Server Error When First Loading App

Tags: python, django

I am new to programming.  So bear with me.  I am following a tutorial to learn Django and Python.  I tried to start running a server to see if my basic app would work, but I get the below error.  I welcome any guidance you can provide.

```html
tom-python@linux:~/todolist$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f58d8103d08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 767, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 727, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/tom-python/todolist/todolist/urls.py", line 21
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `which python` ?

Comment: You're going to have to include the contents of `urls.py` but my guess is that you're missing a comma.

Comment: `SyntaxError` is a kind of errors that mean that you have made some literal mistake, or used wrong syntax somewhere (Tracebacks usually shows exact place where error occurred, usually last lines of traceback) - 21 line of your `urls.py` file.

Comment: WPercy and Chiefir, your hints were enough to help me figure this out.  The tutorial was modeling pre-Django 2.0 syntax.  I made adjustments and and up and running.  Thank you very much for weighing in.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I was following on YouTube modeled pre-Django 2.0 syntax, but I am using Django 2.0.6.  This was causing me some errors.  The comments to my question here provided enough of a hint to push me in the right direction and solve the error.  Thanks.